# Node Sass version issues when attempting to import custom scss into app.js

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, sass, node-sass

I've stumbled upon several articles here on stack that led to different issues and/or didn't resolve my issues.
The issue started when I attempted to import a custom scss file into my app.js in order to override bootstrap theme colors. My app is built using React.

These are my style imports in App.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./shards-dashboard/styles/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.css";
import "./scss/styles.scss";
```

After installing node-sass I got the infamous error:
`Error: Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.`

I uninstalled node-sass and installed version 4.14.1.
This got rid of the compatibility errors but turned up a new error:

```
./src/scss/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/scss/styles.scss)
undefined
^
      Invalid CSS after "  */": expected selector, was "(function (global, "
      in C:\Users\Stephanie\Documents\Projects\BidRL\bidrl-front\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js (line 6, column 1)
```

If I commented out the custom scss import in app js it compiled successfully, but of course I want my custom scss to work.

A few other posts on here recommended upgrading Node. So I upgraded Node from v14.15.5 to v16.3.0 and got an error:

```
`Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)`
```

I reinstalled node-sass without specifying any versions ( "node-sass": "^6.0.0")
and now I'm back at square one with the incompatibility error.
I'll also add that I tried saving as dev dependencies with no resolution.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
  }
```

Anybody able to find a fix for this?

Comment: " Invalid CSS after "  */": expected selector, was " Usually this Error occurs when your '###.scss' starts with a comment in the first line.. see if that is the case..
Secondly, you might be importing an a.scss file which is starting with a comment so check them if you find a comment on first-line get rid of them

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case the invalid CSS error was resolved by commenting out the bootstrap import in my scss file:

```
// Required
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #fb7906,
);

/* finally, import Bootstrap */
@import "bootstrap"; //COMMENTED OUT THIS LINE AND IT COMPILED
```

Answer (score 0):

In app.js or wherever the css is being imported, make sure to import css and not scss. The script to run scss will create a css file and that's what should be imported.